# Finding the limiting distribution for a Binomial-related random variable

Tags: limits, probability-theory, statistics, weak-convergence

A foreword that this isn't homework, rather exam review without solutions.

So the question asks that given $X_{n} \sim \text{Bin}(n,\theta)$, find the limiting distribution of $U_{n} = \frac{X_{n}}{n}\left(1-\frac{X_{n}}{n}\right)$.

I figured out that I can rewrite $X_{n}$ as $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}Z_{k}$ where $Z_{k}$ is a sequence of i.i.d Bernouilli trials, and then $\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}Z_{k}}{n} = \theta$ by the Weak Law of Large Numbers, so I have $\frac{X_{n}}{n}$ figured out. But with this more complicated form, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Wouldn't it be $\theta(1-\theta)$?

Comment: @EA304GT That seems legit. How would I justify it though?